# How to get random item from a list in python3 without any module

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I am using Python 3.9 & have a list `list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` I want to get a random item from the list without using any module like there is a module `random` in Python and a function `random.choice(list1)` I can use this but is there another way to get a random item from a list in Python without using any module?

Comment: What is wrong with using `random`? It's a built-in part of python.

Comment: Yes there is a way, by reimplementing the features of the `random` module.

Comment: Are you asking this question for learning purposes?

Comment: As others have asked: **why** `without using any module`? The Python language offers [only a very small number of so-called "built-in" functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) which don't require any module `import`. None of which generate random numbers. On the other hand, it offers a [very large "batteries-included" standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library) that does _exactly_ what you need. So, again, to give you useful advice about this question, it's helpful to know _why_ you don't want to use the obvious choice of standard library modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Random and pseudorandom number generators will ultimately rely on some kind of module, if only to get a seed needed to produce pseudorandom numbers. One common example of a seed is `time.time` found in the `time` module, though it's not necessarily a good one. The only way without a module is to choose a fixed seed, but then only a fixed sequence of numbers is possible.

Besides the seed, there is the algorithm. One popular choice is the *linear congruential generator* (LCG). This algorithm is appropriate for learning purposes; however, LCGs are far from perfect and should not be used in security applications or serious simulations. See this answer: [How to sync a PRNG between C#/Unity and Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59829276/how-to-sync-a-prng-between-c-unity-and-Python/59831276#59831276)

There are two more things involved in the solution: generating a uniform random integer, and choosing a uniform random item from a list.

- Generating a uniform random integer in [0, n); that is, building `RNDINTEXC(n)`. For that, see [Melissa O'Neill's page](https://www.pcg-random.org/posts/bounded-rands.html). Or if you have pseudorandom or random bits, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046918).
- Choosing a uniform random item from a list, doing `list[RNDINTEXC(len(list))]`.

Answer (score 1):

unless you want to create your own function
**Method 1**

```py
import random
import math

variable = yourarray[math.floor(random.random()*len(yourarray))]
print(variable)
```

**Method 2**

```py
import random
import math

def shuffle(array): 
        currentIndex = len(array);
        temporaryValue= 0;
        randomIndex = 0;
      
        while (0 != currentIndex): 
            randomIndex = math.floor(random.random() * currentIndex);
            currentIndex -= 1;
      
            temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
            array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
            array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
        
      
        return array
yourarray = shuffle(yourarray)
print(yourarray[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `random` module, you can use `time` module to generate pseudorandom integers.

```
import time

def get_random_number(upper_limit):
    _timestamp = time.time()
    _timestamp = int(_timestamp*1000000)
    return _timestamp % upper_limit

def get_item_from_list(_list):
    choice = get_random_number(len(_list))
    assert choice < len(_list), "Index should be less than length of list"
    return _list[choice]

print(get_item_from_list([10, 20, 13, 24, "ABS", "DEF"]))
```

You can use this to generate random items from a list.

Comment: *"without using any module"* -- *"you can use time module"*

Answer (score -2):

Something like this? Assuming your list contains only str

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

def pick_random(array):
    return(list(set(list1))[0])

print(pick_random(list1))
```

Comment: Questions  - try to run a few times, but it always give the same results? (in Python 3.8)